# How to safely migrate from MacTeX 2013 to 2015?

Tags: texlive, installing, texstudio, auctex, mactex

After downloading the MacTeX 2015 distro of TeXLive, I feel a little skeptical about its installation. I would like to clean up the previous installation of MacTeX 2013 and MacPorts installation of TeXLive 2014. This has to be done safely as I would like the apps that use the old distro to use the new one; specifically TeXStudio and Emacs-AuCTeX. How it should be done and in what order?

Comment: I thought files such as `.sty` are all stored at `/usr/local/texlive/2015` or the like. Any concern about just deleting those folders directly in Finder? Because after all you have TimeMachine... do you?

Comment: Few of the packages are installed manually (like thesis.cls and fontspec.sty) I may be able to relocate them and include in a common ~\Library directory. But the command line and Emacs point to MacPorts-TeXLive installation while TeXStudio points to MacTeX-TeXLive 2013. Redundant, isn't it?

Comment: I do not understand... I meant if you want to keep old distributions, then it is a pain to keep track of setting of TeXStudio and Emacs so that they do not refer to the old distributions anymore. But since you do not need old distributions anymore and you can delete them, TeXStudio and Emacs would either report errors or adapt to the new one. (By the way, `fontspec` is not supposed to be installed manually. Unless by "manually" you mean you clicked buttons in TeX Live Utility.)

Comment: By manually, I mean inserting them directly into the tex tree and running texhash to refresh the ls-R directory listing. Besides, your comment *is* my question here; I don't need the old distros and I need to link TeXStudio and Emacs to the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a steady analysis, I came up with this solution.

As MacPorts-TeXLive-2014 is not of my concern, I uninstalled it.

`sudo port uninstall --follow-dependents texlive-bin`

A fresh installation of MacTeX-2015 was done with default sequence. This installed MacTeX-TeXLive-2015 in `/usr/local/texlive/2015`.

A backup of the previously installed MacTeX-TeXLive-2013 in `/usr/local/texlive/2013` was kept in case of any future reference to the previously installed packages.

This may be a paradox, but after a successful series of LaTeX/XeLaTeX compilation, I really felt that the newly installed MacTeX-2015 is a lot faster than the previous 2014 and 2013 versions.